# how can I get the actual object value of a failed xsd validation

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-validation

I use the following code to validate a xml file against a xsd file.

```
var result = false;
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(xmlPath);

xml.Schemas.Add(null, xsdPath);

try
{
    xml.Validate(null);
    result = true;
}
catch (XmlSchemaValidationException ex)
{
    result = false;
    _logger.Error($"{ex.Message}");
}
```

It works but I only get the error message, I would like to retrieve the actual value in the xml file that fail. For example, in the xsd file I have this

```
<xs:element name="Car" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
   <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="Volvo|Tesla|Skoda"/>
        </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

And the XML file contains the value Ford in the Car element. How can I retrieve the "Ford" value that is failing against the validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, I can add this inside the catch(XmlSchemaValidatorException ex)..

var node = ex.SourceObject as XmlNode;

Then I'm able to get the node.InnerText which contains the faulty value

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as the answer by using the green tick.